# jQuery function which creates div, rewritten in JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have this function which is written in jQuery and creates a div for selected element.

```
var createPlaceholder = function createPlaceholder(height) {
    return $('<div></div>').css({
        height: height + 'px',
        marginTop: (currentIndex > 0 ? -marginTop : -1) + 'px'
    })
    .addClass('placeholder');
};
```

And then is called like this:

```
placeholderHeight = dragging.outerHeight() + marginTop;
placeholder = createPlaceholder(placeholderHeight);
placeholder.insertAfter(dragging);
```

Now the pure JS stuff! I'm trying to do same thing but without jQuery, but i'm always getting undefined errors and parent problems. This is what i did by far:

```
var createPlaceholder = function createPlaceholder(height) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.style.height = height + 'px';
      div.style.marginTop = (currentIndex > 0 ? -marginTop : -1) + 'px';
      div.setAttribute('class', 'placeholder');

      document.body.appendChild(div);
   };

placeholderHeight = dragging.outerHeight() + marginTop;
placeholder = createPlaceholder(placeholderHeight);
placeholder.parentNode.insertBefore(placeholder,dragging.nextSibling);
```

Tried this way:

```
 placeholderHeight = dragging.outerHeight() + marginTop;
 var div = document.createElement('div');
     div.style.height = placeholderHeight + 'px';
     div.style.marginTop = (currentIndex > 0 ? -marginTop : -1) + 'px';
     div.setAttribute('class', 'placeholder');

  div.parentNode.insertBefore(div, dragging[0].nextSibling);
```

I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null

What i'm doing wrong? :/

Comment: What are the errors you get?

Comment: I get: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined on the last line "placeholder.parentNode.insertBefore(placeholder,dragging.nextSibling);"

Comment: Your `createPlaceholder` function is not returning anything.

Comment: Whoops, returns undefined. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I modified your code to a working condition that can be tested on this page itself, because you didn't supply any playground link or the rest of the code...so here it is:

```
var dragging = document.getElementById('question-header');


var createPlaceholder = function createPlaceholder(height) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.cssText = 'height:' + height + 'px; margin-top:' + (currentIndex > 0 ? -marginTop : -1) + 'px';
  div.className = 'placeholder';

  return div;
};

placeholderHeight = dragging.clientHeight + 10;
placeholder = createPlaceholder(placeholderHeight);
dragging.parentNode.insertBefore(placeholder,dragging.nextSibling);
```

Answer (score -2):

I think, variables (currentIndex/marginTop) is being referenced before it has been initialized with a value.

Comment: No, it's not that, they show correctly in div now. I updated my question with my last try.

Comment: try with :
document.body.insertBefore(div, dragging[0].nextSibling);

Comment: document.body.insertBefore(div, dragging.nextSibling);